# Fractal dimension of a set of points in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: fractals

I have a set of points in $\mathbb{R}^2$, of the form:

$\left(\frac{a}{\ell^2},\frac{b}{\ell^3}\right)$

where $\ell>0$ is an integer and $a$ and $b$ are some real positive numbers.

I am interested to know the fractal dimension of this set of points as $\ell$ becomes infinite. Is there a simple way of computing this?

Comment: See [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/125543/22013).

Comment: Thanks corey979! I guess this does it numerically. Do you know if the dimension can be found analytically based on the information I provided?

Comment: @user12588. Based on your comment (that you are looking for an *analytic* solution), it looks like you should've posted this on [math.se] rather than here on the *Mathematica* site.

Comment: I posted this on Mathematics: the answer is (apparently) obvious. Because the set I presented is countable, its Hausdorff measure is zero. Thanks for all your help anyways.

Comment: The assumption that $a,b$ are "positive real numbers" doesn't really restrict matters unless you are asserting these are fixed for all points in the set.  (In which case all these points lie on a common line in the first quadrant)